# How to overlay divs on the right of each line in a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

I want to right-align text to each line in a textarea that a user is typing like this:

[image: Numi screenshot]

It should also support scrolling like this (see how the top is cut off when it's out of view?):

[image: Scrolled numi screenshot]

How might I go about doing that?

EDIT:

Also, any div on the right should animate on hover and when clicked, the contents should be copied to clipboard. Like so:

[image: Align right hover and click]

Answer (score 0):

Just make two different text areas and put one at left and second to right. Then make them look visually like one: for left make `border-right: 0;` for right - `border-left: 0;`

For your task you could use `texterea` and `div` like that:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.textarea-block {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 400px; /* Here you could use % or wh to make it looks better in your app */
}

/* Don't forget to make a clearfix after floats */
.textarea-block:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
}

.left {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 0;
  width: 50%;
}

.right {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="textarea-block">
  <textarea name="" cols="30" rows="10" class="left">First line 
Second line</textarea>
  <div class="right">
    First line <br>Second line
  </div>
</div>
```

Just be sure to make the same `font-size` and `font-family` to textarea and div to make text looks same.

Comment: @Matias That is not full code here. It's just to prove an idea ^_^

Comment: Thanks! However, I should've mentioned this--sorry, I need the text on the right corresponding to the line to have an animation on hover and the text copied on click. I don't know how I'd go about doing that with a second textarea instead of overlayed divs?

Comment: @Matias could you put this requirement in your question as it changes things quite a bit, including you are likely to need some JavaScriopt.

Comment: @Matias I still think the best idea to use 2 textareas. I thought you're making some kind of chat. Is it some kind of calculator? In that case for sure better to use textarea + div. So on changes in textarea you could bind some script which place result to div. Also you could add second script which copied to clipboard it content.

Comment: @Matias also could you provide your JS code so we could help you ^_^

Comment: yeah that's pretty much what I have, except divs are absolute positioned and have a `top: ${props.idx * 28.8 - 1}px;` (idx is the index, which line # it is). This is far from optimal as the numbers were just found empirically and it gets misaligned with the left after enough lines, not to mention it won't work for users of different font sizes

Comment: Sure, here's my div's JS code: https://github.com/SwiftWinds/numbra/blob/main/src/Answer.tsx. And here's the textarea's JS code: https://github.com/SwiftWinds/numbra/blob/main/src/App.tsx. Sorry if the code is a bit messy right now. I'm just trying to get it to work first and I'll clean it up afterwards

Comment: @Vetos sorry for the bump, but any way you could update your answer to use a textarea + div and align the div perfectly with each line of the textarea?

Comment: @Matias Let me try ^_^

Comment: @Matias I've updated my answer to make textarea left and div to right;

Comment: @Matias if it help please mark it as right answer for your question ^_^